# Adding custom field to product category and show it to shop/category shop page

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

Hy i am using this tutorial to add custom field in backend shop category page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469841/adding-custom-field-to-product-category/40183439#40183439
and now i want to show that field value under product image on shop page, Brand page ,category products listing page or any page which shows multiple products

Comment: There's a 'to retrieve data' section in that answer. Does that not work for you?

Comment: its working fine on category page but not on brand or shop page it should work like it should show on store wide in that product if it is in that category

Comment: Hey thanks for your response its working fine if its only category page. Like here: adasat.com/product-category/affordables-from-79-aed its coming But if i wish to expose/echo it on product page data is not comming: adasat.com/product/adasat-fashion-sunshade-blk

Comment: i am using following for which is working fine only in category page but not in product detail page : global $wp_query; $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); $wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true); $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); echo '<div class="coupon-text">'.get_term_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'wh_meta_title', true).'</div>'; ?> But in product page i check in inspect element only div comming not its values